# Missing Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint.dll and Microsoft.Gestures.Protocol.dll

Tags: c#, dll, azure-cognitive-services, gesture-recognition

I want to set up a gesture controlled project.

The Project uses the Intel Real Sense SR300 and I have installed the Intel Real Sense SDK 2.0.

I also installed the Project Prague SDK for gesture control. The `Microsoft.Gestures.dll` is installed. But it doesnot install the

```
Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint.dll
Microsoft.Gestures.Protocol.dll
```

So I am incapable to reference the two dll's in my project. Thus, means that I cannot use gesture controlling in my project.

Is there a way to get these dll's on anotherway? Or is there an other solution to use gesture control?

Comment: Did this work for you? If yes, please mark my answer. If not please update your Question why it did suits you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To find the required `DLL's` you have to use the `%MicrosoftGesturesInstallDir%` Environment Variable. It points to a location in your `AppData` Folder:

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Prague\PragueVersions\LatestVersion`

Here are all the required files stored and get synchronized.

Or use following paths:

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Prague\PragueVersions\LatestVersion\SDK\Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint.dll`
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Prague\PragueVersions\LatestVersion\Microsoft.Gestures.Protocol.dll`

`%MicrosoftGesturesInstallDir%\SDK\Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint.dll`
`%MicrosoftGesturesInstallDir%\Microsoft.Gestures.Protocol.dll`

---

From the [official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gestures/#creating-gestures-in-project-prague) of Project Prague:

> Please note that in order for the above code to compile, you will need
>   to reference the following assemblies, located in the directory
>   indicated by the **MicrosoftGesturesInstallDir** environment variable:
>
> - Microsoft.Gestures.dll
> - Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint.dll
> - Microsoft.Gestures.Protocol.dll